urlscheme variable passing does not seem to work when app first opens?
urlscheme variable passing does not seem to work when app first opens (cold starts) - but does when it remains open?
    private void Awake()
    {
        if (Instance == null)
        {
            Instance = this;
            Application.deepLinkActivated += onDeepLinkActivated;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Application.absoluteURL))
            {
                // Cold start and Application.absoluteURL not null so process Deep Link.
                onDeepLinkActivated(Application.absoluteURL);
            }
            // Initialize DeepLink Manager global variable.
            else deeplinkURL = "[none]";
            DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
        }
        else
        {
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }

        print(">>> " + Application.absoluteURL);
    }

